# XmlSchema assert the size with another element

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I am trying to make an xmlSchema to validate my game maps.

I have a global element defined as following

```
    <xs:element name="size">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="rowCount"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="columnCount"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

And I have to other elements which I want to have the same size as the ones defined in the global element.

So the min and max of the following elements to follow the size set in the global element. I'm using XSD 1.1 so I can use assert, but I don't know the syntax to correctly define the rule.

```
<xs:element name="rows" minOccurs & maxOccurs=VALUE OF size.rowCount>

<xs:element name="tiles" minOccurs & maxOccurs=VALUE OF size.columnCount>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and actually put some effort into conforming with the required syntax for assertions.  There are plenty of examples on this site to use as starting points.

Comment: @kjhughes How do I refer in an assertion to a value of another element? I have seen the 'count' method, but only seen that the count should equal to a given number not to another element's value.

Comment: Re-read my first comment.  Here is but one example that you should use to improve, if not outrightly answer, your question: [**Max occurs of element which depend on value of other element using XML Schema**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37642086/290085)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write, for example

```
<xs:assert test="every $table in descendant::table 
                 satisfies count($table/row) = size/@rowCount"/>
```

But the details depend on your exact structure.

The important thing is that the assertion belongs to the object that contains all the values involved in the condition - an assertion can't look outside the subtree of the element on which it is defined. And the XPath expressions are relative to that containing element. Also, remember to use namespace prefixes if the elements are in a namespace.